# Why are my tables not updating in my server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created several tables for a college assignment (these are all in MySQL Workbench). 
I switched over to my server, and none of my tables are updated.

For example, I had a table with `ClassID, ClassCode, ClassName, and Description`.

ClassCode and Description were of datatypes INT and DATE, respectively.

I changed those in my schema to VARCHAR(45) for both, but they are not updated in my server.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the console in MySql workbench. Ensure that you are actually making the changes to the server, where you think you are making it

Comment: Did you click `Apply` after making changes (it's in the lower right part of the screen)? First time I used it I completely overlooked it.